# Fancybox jQuery to play YouTube playlist?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I can get a YouTube video to play with Fancybox but I can not get a YouTube playlist to work.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Is this question about opening hidden accordions or playing YouTube playlists?

Comment: Playing YouTube playlists with Fancybox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. See a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aTgsN/) (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736744/fancybox-youtube-channel-embed)).

I was doing my selection based on the rel attribute and not classes so I left out the fancybox classes in the html anchor. Once I added in this fancybox class I was good to go.

```
<a class="fancybox.iframe" ... > ... </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a Youtube play list just changing the href on their anchors. Pay special attention to listType parameter. This parameter can take two values​​: playlist and user_uploads. If you want show a playlist use the first value. However if you just want to display a channel you must use the second value. In turn, the value for the list attribute should be the id of the list for the first case and the Youtube user name for the second.

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=user_uploads&list=Google"></a>

<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=playlist&list=PL590L5WQmH8f_0qlZ-tKrtbfw4n0jyHQh"></a>
```