# Fancybox Youtube Channel Embed

Tags: youtube, fancybox, youtube-api

Hopefully a simple one - I'm trying to embed my Youtube channel (not a specific video, which is what all existing answers are aimed at, it seems) in a Fancybox. The popup appears fine, but due to Youtube's

```
    X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
```

... the content isn't displaying. I've included the origin parameter in the URL, but I still get denied due to the above. I'm probably just using the wrong syntax for channels or similar: could anyone help? The URL I'm using (without success) is below (actual channel/domain substituted):

```
    http://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=user_uploads&list=MyChannelName&origin=http://www.mydomain.com/
```

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me - http://jsfiddle.net/aTgsN/

Comment: Hmmm, yes, it does for me too (within jsfiddle). Curiouser and curiouser. I guess the problem is not where I thought it was! Thank you.

Comment: btw, maybe you are using media helper? it seems not to work, I`ll update the regexp